# libmysqlclient-dev installation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I am trying bundle install and by halfway i get error saying:

```
Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
and while trying to do as suggested, again dependencies arrise..
  libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 is to be installed

 umes@umes-pc:/var/www/MachingShop_portal_v2$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: upgrades and updates are all executed ...

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue in following the instructions for installing Open edX on a Ubuntu 14.04 server where I know the installation scripts are targeted for Ubuntu 12.04. Is it possible you are on a different OS version than the instructions you're following?

Answer (score 2):

Use this command and retry.

```
sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: It worked for me! I was having a similar issue when trying to install libmysqlclient-dev in a docker imagem python:3.8-slim. Error message: _libc6-dev : Breaks: libmysqlclient-dev (<= 8.0.29-1) but 8.0.29-1 is to be installed_. Does anyone understand the reason for this error and why @Bigmwaj answer solves it?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command again and hope that will install all necessary dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get update & upgrade
```

then try installing `libmysqlclient-dev` again.

if you face more error, you can try the following ways. That problem is very similar to yours.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73522

Comment: ya i did that too.. no luck

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient18 : Breaks: libmysqlclient18:i386 (!= 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 is to be installed
 libmysqlclient18:i386 : Breaks: libmysqlclient18 (!= 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1) but 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: did you try the following command?
sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends libmysqlclient18

Comment: ya i did and tried to install again but threw error

Comment: can try this:
sudo apt-get -f install libmysqlclient18